# How can I create a CheckboxGroup linking each checkbox to boolean values of an object?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have an object with a bunch of boolean fields as below:

```
public class ContainsBooleans {
    private boolean aBoolean = true;
    private boolean anotherBoolean = false;
...
}
```

With getters and setters as usual. I'm trying to create a CheckboxGroup which contains a Checkbox for each boolean field in the object, binding to the respective fields.

I've tried creating a Checkbox individually for each field, but I can't figure out how to add them to the CheckboxGroup (and also can't figure out which type the CheckboxGroup should be), as if I have CheckboxGroup, I obviously can't add Checkboxes to the CheckboxGroup, and I can't figure out how the mapping from each Checkbox to the boolean is done.

Basically my POJO class has a number of booleans which can be enabled/disabled, and I want the interface to have a checkbox representing each.

I don't have much more code to show at all really, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on CheckboxGroup, so I'm not even sure where to start

Comment: If you change your logic to have a List<String> as options and use RadioButtonGroup you have a similar behavior you desire, where you can check the options later on (present in list = true, missing = false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no one-liner shortcut.  The reason it's not "easy" is
because this looks like you are pushing something beyond a boundary,
that should have better stayed on the other side.  If I'd had to guess,
I'd say your are dealing with a database row and you want to edit
directly in the GUI, but the modelling of the data in the table does not
match up, what the actual domain or even the GUI representation of it
is.

So the proper way to handle this would be to use a model for the GUI
that at least hides the implementation detail, that is giving you
a headache.  Hide the db-implementation details from the GUI.

If you absolutely have to use that class for whatever reason: consider
adding a synthetic getter/setter for a `Set<SomeEnum>` that represents
the group of booleans you want to represent in the GUI.  Then you put an
enum for every set boolean in the set and vice versa.  Then use the
`CheckboxGroup<Set<SomeEnum>>` in your GUI.

If even that is out of the question, then you could put this
getter/setter in when binding the form (e.g. instead of binding via
property name); basically the same as above, but without changing the
original class.

Comment: This is more or less how I ended up doing it - I use an `EnumSet` and a switch statement, so anything in the `EnumSet` calls the necessary setter method. Then do the inverse with `EnumSet.complementOf()`
I'll mark this one as the accepted answer